# In python flask, how do you get the path parameters outside of the route function?

Tags: python, flask

In flask, you can define path parameters like so:

```
@app.route('/data/<section>')
def data(section):
   print section
```

In The above example, you can access the section variable only from the data endpoint (unless you pass it around in function parameter)

You can also get the query parameters by accessing the request object. this works from the endpoint function as well as any other called function, without needing to pass anything around

```
request.args['param_name']
```

my question is: is in possible to access the path parameter (like section above) in the same way as the query parameters?

Comment: Do you mean the actual path of the request (e.g. '/data/1') or the string literal that was matched (e.g. '/data/<section>')?

Comment: I think what you mean is that `request` and `session` work like globals and you would like `section` to work as a global. What you can do is store it into `flask.g`, which is an application global that can store arbitrary python objects for the length of the request. I imagine that `section` actually is already in `request` somewhere.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

It's possible to use `request.view_args`.
The [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.view_args) defines it this way:

> A dict of view arguments that matched the request.

Here's an example:

```
@app.route("/data/<section>")
def data(section):
    assert section == request.view_args['section']
```

Comment: @ulienc: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks

Comment: how can i use it in a query? for eg @app.route("/data/<tablename>") def data(tablename): sql='desc tablename'