# Flask RESTful API Translations

Tags: python, api, flask-restful, language-translation

I have an API which returns a JSON list when navigating to the url per say http://www.example.com/list.

The sample JSON list is as such:

```
{
   "name": "This is a name"
}
```

But i also want to provide this exact JSON list in another language per say french as such:

```
{
   "name": "C'est un nom"
}
```

What i managed to do is having 2 different urls:

1 for English: http://www.example.com/en/list.
1 for French: http://www.example.com/fr/list.

And then in my code i have two classes, again 1 for English and 1 for French:

```
class ItemList_En(Resource):

def get(self):
    return {"name": "This is a name"}

class ItemList_Fr(Resource):

def get(self):
    return {"name": "C'est un nom"}

api.add_resource(ItemList_En, "/en/list")
api.add_resource(ItemList_Fr, "/fr/list")
```

I wanted to know if this is the only way of doing this ? Is there a better way that i don't know of since i am new to Python and Flask. Grateful if someone could help me out.

Comment: Maybe you can try this, have single class for translation process and from url path get the language value and have conditional statement inside it. Like: `/<lang>/list` where `lang` can be "en", "fr" etc. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41493168/3523510

Comment: Oh yeah, that seems feasible. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Flask-Babel package for multi-language support. https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Babel/

Comment: I think this is what i was looking for! I will try this and revert to you. Thank you so much for the help